# Controlling animation from seekbar

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am new to android. I have a lottie json file and based upon a seekbar want to control the amount of animation it is showing like at 0 the animation should start and at 50 it should show only 50 and finish at 100 also .

I havent tried anything so far as have no clue on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control lottie animation file with seekbar.
But you can edit your lottie animation file [here](https://lottiefiles.com/editor)

Comment: By controlling can't i animate accordingto the progress of seekbar

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what i am trying to acheive is something like a swipe feature. where suppose you have 200 frames in lottie animation and then your seekbaar you control which frame is currently shown ..just like a videoplayer

Comment: I think it's not possible to do with lottie animation since lottie animation file is exported as a whole json file.